# recursively Searching Binary Search Tree by Name

Tags: c#, search, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have a binary search tree that stores details of countries financial situation.  I have added all the countries.  Now I want to search by country name.

I have a **find** method in my BST class, but it doesn't print anything when I call it.

```
 public object find(string country)
    {
        return find(country, root);
    }


    private object find(string item, Node<T> tree)
    {
        int compare;
        while (tree != null)
        {
            string[] outcome = tree.Data.ToString().Split(',');
            compare = outcome[0].CompareTo(item);
            if (compare == 0)
            {
                return tree.Data;
            }
            else if (compare > 0)
            {
                tree = tree.Left;
            }
            else if (compare < 0)
            {
                tree = tree.Right;
            }
        }

        return null;
```

This code is in my **form** class:

```
 public object findcountryInformation(string countryName)
    {
        object result = myTree.find(countryName);
        return result;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        object result = findcountryInformation(text);
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        // expected output is details of the countries selected from the listbox 
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also, you should have already tried to debug this, if only with well-placed **print** statements in the private **find** method.  Make sure that you know the argument values on every call and which branch you took.  This should show the logic problem quickly enough.  Do this with the outer routines as well.  For instance, does this return a **null** value or a blank string?